# Induced Sheaf on Subspaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Suppose that $X$ is a topological space, $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf (of abelian groups, rings, ideals, modules) on $X$ and $Y \subset X$. Do you know a natural way to get an induced sheaf on $Y$ from $\mathcal{F}$?

If $Y$ is open, the answer is straight forward. I will be happy with an answer assuming the following extra conditions: $Y$ is closed and $X$ is irreducible.

Comment: What do you mean by "induced"? Is the pushforward not considered acceptable?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. You have an inclusion $Y \hookrightarrow$ X and a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$, you don't have a sheaf on $Y$, what do you "pushforward"?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your problem. What about pullback? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_image_sheaf

Comment: Uhm, this probably works. I remember seeing the "particular" construction (by particular, I mean with a direct formula) from some text but I cannot recall exactly what it is right now. Working out the sheafification in the pullback construction, perhaps one would get a direct formula. I'll check this tomorrow and response to your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can get a direct "formula" for the set of sections, but this is useless in all situations I know of. Better think of pullback as left adjoint of pushforward, and the latter is easy to describe.

Comment: I came up directly with a formula and also worked out from the pullback and verify that they give one the same sheaf. Here is the "direct" formula. Given any open $V \subset Y$, one defines $\mathcal{F}(V)$ as the set consisting all functions $t: V \rightarrow \cup_{p \in V}\mathcal{F}_p$ such that: 1) $t(p) \in \mathcal{F}_p$ for all $p$;
2) for every $p \in V$, there exists $U \subset X$ open and $s \in \mathcal{F}(U)$ such that $p \in U \cap S \subset V$ and $s_q = t(q)$ for all $q \in U \cap S$.

Thanks guys, for your answers!